# How to count all Subdocument in a Collection using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here i need to count all sub-documents in a collection using mongoose

this is my routes

```
router.get('/all-booking', function(req, res){
        BookingList.find({}, 'booking', function (err, docs) {
            if(err)
                throw err;
            res.json(docs);
        });
    });
```

Here In **BookingList** `booking` is a  `subdocument array`, by above query am getting all sub-documents in Collection, But I need to `Count` all sub-document, How can i do this.

Help will be appreciated

Comment: its showing me the records length, not sub-documents count

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation to get the count:

```
router.get('/all-booking', function(req, res){
    var pipeline = [
        {   // Get the length of the booking array
            "$project": {
                "booking_size": { "$size": "$booking" }
            }
        },
        {   // Get the total length of all the booking fields
            "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "count": { "$sum": "$booking_size" }
            }
        }
    ]
    BookingList.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, result) {
        if(err)
            throw err;
        console.log(result[0].count); // Prints the count of all the booking sub-documents in the collection
        res.json(result);
    });

    // Or using the fluent aggregate pipeline builder API
    BookingList.aggregate()
        .project({ "booking_size": { "$size": "$booking" } })
        .group({ "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": "$booking_size" } })
        .exec(function (err, result) {
            if(err)
                throw err;
            console.log(result[0].count); // Prints the count of all the booking sub-documents in the collection
            res.json(result);
        });
});
```